# why am i getting a 404 for this svg in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have two svg files called **play.svg** and **pause.svg** that are being used in another file called **index.js**. The directory looks like this:

```
app
 components
  index.js
 pages
  _app.js
 public
  play.svg
  pause.svg
```

In **index.js** is this:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
export default class Player extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
    <Image
     className="play-button"
     src={`/${isPlaying ? '../public/pause' : '../public/play'}.svg`}
     width="140"
     height="140"
     onClick={togglePlayPause}
    />
   )
 }
}
```

In **_app.js** is this:

```
import Player from '../components/player'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 <Player />
}
export default MyApp
```

This results in a 404 for both svg files: `GET http://localhost:57739/public/play.svg 404 (Not Found)`

Why is this `http://localhost:57739/public/play.svg` returning a 404?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `../public` from the path and just use `/play.svg` or `/pause.svg` NextJS adds the path to the `webroot/public/`

https://dev.to/dolearning/importing-svgs-to-next-js-nna